# Showing extra menu when viewing Views

Tags: drupal, view, slideshow, drupal-views

I making a site.
I've managed to make a views slideshow of some photo's.
I also manually made a extra menu where i want to link other views.

The problem is, this menu isnt showed when viewing a views slideshow.
Other standard menu items always showing...

Extra menu shows when not in slideshow:
[image]

Extra menu doesnt show when in a slideshow:[image]

Comment: How is that extra menu placed on your pages?  Through the context module or through the block's configuration page or directly in the template file?

Comment: @Boriana through the block's